# Как задать координаты объекту при его создании в Canvas?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проблема следующая:
Есть префаб объекта - dummy,
есть `Canvas` а в нем `gameobject GameField`, который рисует игровое поле,
есть массив координат каждой ячейки поля `CellsCoordinats[,]`.
После отрисовки поля создается объект в координатах этого поля, 
например в `0f, 0f, -1f` (левый, верхний угол).

```
GameObject gem = Instantiate(dummy, CellsCoordinats[0, 0], Quaternion.identity, parrentObject.transform);
```

объект создается, но в каких-то других космических координатах.
Ладно... пытаюсь вернуть его назад в нужное место

```
gem.transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, -1f);
```

но объект никуда не перемещается. Подскажите, что я не так делаю?

Comment: Все таки правильно было так `GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3(-246f, -242f, -1f);`                                         Проблема была скорее всего в якорях. После их сброса и обновления все заработало. Xumera_hZ спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

У Canvas своя система позиционирования, основанная на RectTransform, позиционируйте от нее. И еще когда цепляете gameObject к Parent в Canvas'e то нужно следить еще за localScale(он может уменьшиться или очень большим стать)

Comment: Так я координаты RectTransform` овские и забиваю. Или их надо не через `gameObject.transform` забивать а через какую-то иную команду? На счет scale - да, я заметил такой финт. )

Comment: RectTransform унаследовано от transform, они немного разную природу используют. Тут надо брать GetComponent<RectTransform>().

Comment: Если Вы о чем-то, вроде: `gem.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3(-246f, -242f, -1f);` - то так я тоже пробовал. Координаты меняются, но все равно не те, что нужны... (

Comment: А position вместо localPosition пробовали? локальная позиция относительно родителя встает, и это может быть не те координаты которые надо.( то есть допустим родитель в позиции 100,100, то если в него положить обьект и через localPosition назначить 50,50, то глобальная позиция будет 150,150)